# Why doesn't django-badges award a badge when the criteria is met?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement django-badges in my project, and I'm trying to award the Autobiographer badge for filling out profile fields, yet no badge is ever awarded (confirmed since nothing is created in database). However if I create a view that would return the progress of the badge for a user using either get_progress() or get_progress_percentage(), it shows that the needed criteria is met.  For example, my test view looks like this:

```
#views.py
def badges(request, name):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=name)
    badge = Badge.objects.get(id='autobiographer')
    progress = badge.meta_badge.get_progress(user)
    progress_percentage = badge.meta_badge.get_progress_percentage(user)
    return render('badges.html', {'badge': badge, 'progress': progress, 'progress_percent': progress_percent}, request=request)

#badge_template.html
{{ progress }}
<br />
{{ progress_percent }}

#meta_badges.py
class Autobiographer(badges.MetaBadge):
    id = "autobiographer"
    model = BaseProfile
    one_time_only = True

    title = "Autobiographer"
    description = "Completed 5 User Profile Fields"
    level = "1"

    progress_start = 0
    progress_finish = 5

    def get_user(self, instance):
        return instance.user

    def get_progress(self, user):
        has_avatar = 1 if user.get_profile().avatar else 0
        has_city = 1 if user.get_profile().city else 0
        has_twitter = 1 if user.get_profile().twitter else 0
        has_facebook = 1 if user.get_profile().facebook else 0
        has_linkedin = 1 if user.get_profile().linkedin else 0
        has_google_plus = 1 if user.get_profile().google_plus else 0
        has_tumblr = 1 if user.get_profile().tumblr else 0
        return has_avatar + has_city + has_twitter + has_facebook + has_linkedin + has_google_plus + has_tumblr

    def check_avatar(self, instance):
        return instance.user.get_profile().avatar

    def check_city(self, instance):
        return instance.user.get_profile().city

    def check_twitter(self, instance):
        return instance.user.get_profile().twitter

    def check_facebook(self, instance):
        return instance.user.get_profile().facebook

    def check_linkedin(self, instance):
        return instance.user.get_profile().linkedin

    def check_tumblr(self, instance):
        return instance.user.get_profile().tumblr

    def check_google_plus(self, instance):
        return instance.user.get_profile().google_plus
```

If user1 has 5 profile fields filled out, example.com/badges/user1 looks like:

```
5
100
```

Anybody successfully use django-badges and know what I'm missing, or is there another badge solution that works? It seemed easy enough to use, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Anyone even have a suggestion of something to try? Don't care if it might not work, just need something else to try, even if you have never actually used django-badges yourself.  From the looks of it, not many people have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you're still using django-badges or still have this problem, because the post is a month old. I'm using django-badges in my project too and it works fine.

I think the problem in your code is that you're mixing two concepts, the progress-data and the real criteria to win a badge. The app will only award one of your users if he fills in all of the seven Profile Fields required for the badge. The progress on the other hand evaluates only that five fields are filled.

You could implement a single check method that looks just like the get_progress one, returning True if five or more fields have been filled:

```
    def check_fields(self, instance):
        has_avatar = 1 if instance.user.get_profile().avatar else 0
        has_city = 1 if instance.user.get_profile().city else 0
        has_twitter = 1 if instance.user.get_profile().twitter else 0
        has_facebook = 1 if instance.user.get_profile().facebook else 0
        has_linkedin = 1 if instance.user.get_profile().linkedin else 0
        has_google_plus = 1 if instance.user.get_profile().google_plus else 0
        has_tumblr = 1 if instance.user.get_profile().tumblr else 0
        fields_filled = has_avatar + has_city + has_twitter + has_facebook + has_linkedin + has_google_plus + has_tumblr
        return fields_filled >= 5
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I appreciate it! As always, turns out I was making a stupid mistake and over-complicating things. I took a break away from badges to get other things done that needed to be completed, and now that I finally came back to it, it works.  Thanks a lot for the help!